# Is <- only accessible by the compiler

Tags: scala, syntax, compiler-construction, macros

Scala's `<-` arrow seems a bit strange. Most operators are implemented somewhere in the source as a function, defined on a data type, either directly or implicitly. `<-` on the other hand only seems to unusable outside of a `for` comprehension, where it acts as a syntactic element used to signal the binding of a new variable in a monadic context (via `map`).

This is the only instance I can think of where Scala has an operator-looking syntactical element that is only usable in a specific context, and isn't an actual function.

Am I wrong about how `<-` works? Is it a special case symbol used just by the compiler, or is there some way a developer could use this behavior when writing their own code?

For example, would it be possible to write a macro to transform

```
forRange (i <- 0 to 10) { print(i) }
```

into

```
{ var i = 0; while (i <= 10) { print(i) } }
```

instead of its standard `map` equivalent? As far as I can tell, any usage of `i <- ...` outside of a `for` context causes an exception due to referencing an unknown value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes `<-` is a reserved operator in Scala. It's a compiler thing.

**Foreach**

There is a strong distinction between `foreach` and `for yield`, but the syntax is only syntactic sugar, transformed at compile time.

`for (i <- 1 to 10) { statement }` expression is translated to:

```
Range.from(1, 10).foreach(..)
```

Multiple variables:
`for (i <- 1 to 10; y <- 2 to 100) {..}` becomes:

`Range.from(1, 10).foreach(
    el => {Range.from(2, 100).foreach(..)});`

With all the variations given by:

`for (x <- someList)` = `someList.foreach(..)`.

Put simply, they all get de-sugared to `foreach` statements. The specific `foreach` being called is given by the collection used.

**For yield**

The `for yield` syntax is sugar for `flatMap` and `map`. The `stay in the monad` rule applies here.

`for (x <- someList) yield {..}` gets translated to a `someList.flatMap(..)`.

Chained operations become hierarchical chains of `map/flatMap` combos:

`for {
  x <- someList; y <- SomeOtherList
} yield {}` becomes:

`someList.flatMap(x => {
    y.flatMap(..)
 });` and so on.

**The point**

The point is that the `<-` operator is nothing more than syntactic sugar to make code more readable, but it always gets replaced at compile time.

**To emphasize Rob's point**

Rob makes excellent examples of other Scala syntactic sugar.

**A context bound**

```
package somepackage;
class Test[T : Manifest] {}
```

Is actually translated to:

`class Test[T](implicit evidence: Manifest[T])`

As proof, try to alias a type with a context bound:

`type TestAlias[T : Manifest] = somepackage.Test // error, the : syntax can't be used.`.
It is perhaps easy to see how the `: Manifest` part is actually not a type a parameter.

It's just easier to type `class Test[T : Manifest]` rather than `class Test[T](implicit evidence: Manifest[T]`.

Comment: I suppose Scala has spoiled me a bit. There have been a number of things I originally thought were syntactic sugar, specific to the compiler, that ended up being built on language features. It's one of my favorite things about Scala; a lot of its design avoids special-case things. Unfortunately I don't know how else you _would_ design this. +1 and an **accept** for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `<-` operator is a reserved word in the language (see the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), page 4), but it isn't alone. `=>` is also a reserved word rather than a function. (Also `_`, `:`, `=`, `<:`, `<%`, `>:`, `#`, and `@`.) So you couldn't create a function with that name. I don't believe you could adapt it the way you're suggesting, either (though perhaps someone more clever will know a way). You could create a function called `` `<-` `` (with surrounding back-ticks), but that would probably be more awkward than it deserves.

Comment: I should've expected that => was the same. Just hadn't thought about it. +1 for the useful info. It's a shame that it's a compiler feature rather than built on a language feature. I don't know how you would do it, but Scala has surprised me by making a lot of things that *look* like syntactic sugar out of simple language constructs (`->` to create tuples, for example).